# Force check of each entry when applying template?

Tags: xslt, xpath, symphony-cms

I have a template which fetches images and then outputs them into one of two templates.

I would like it to track each individual image and output based on the values of each one. Currently, if one image is wide, it outputs them all according to the wide template. I would rather utilize both templates.

```
<xsl:template name="get-images">
    <xsl:param name="image-entry"/>
    <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="($image-entry/image/meta/@width) &gt; ($image-entry/image/meta/@height)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$image-entry/image" mode="wide">
            <xsl:with-param name="image-class" select="'full-width'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="caption-class" select="'full-width-caption'"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$image-entry/image" mode="tall">
            <xsl:with-param name="image-class" select="'center'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="caption-class" select="'full-width-caption'"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image" mode="wide">
    <xsl:param name="image-class" />
    <xsl:param name="caption-class" />

    <a href="{$root}/image/full{@path}/{filename}">
        <img src="{$root}/image/wide{@path}/{filename}" alt="{../description}" class="{$image-class}"/>
    </a>

    <p class="{$caption-class}">
        Image courtesy of: <a href="{../source}"><xsl:value-of select="../title"/></a>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image" mode="tall">
    <xsl:param name="image-class" />
    <xsl:param name="caption-class" />

    <span class="centered">
        <a href="{$root}/image/full{@path}/{filename}">
            <img src="{$root}/image/tall{@path}/{filename}" alt="{../description}" class="{$image-class}"/>
        </a>
    </span>

    <p class="{$caption-class}">
        Image courtesy of: <a href="{../source}"><xsl:value-of select="../title"/></a>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Bonus question: How can I ignore the caption if value source doesn't exist?

```
            <article-images field-id="24" subsection-id="5" items="1">
                <item id="109" creation-date="2014-04-24T05:16:52+01:00">
                    <image size="317 KB" path="/uploads" type="image/jpeg">
                        <filename>funny-lolcat.jpg</filename>
                        <meta creation="2014-04-24T05:16:52+01:00" width="1600" height="1200" />
                    </image>
                    <description mode="formatted"><p>Aww!</p>
</description>
                    <title handle="" />
                    <source handle="" />
                </item>
            </article-images>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of two modes, use one mode and move the wide vs not-wide logic into the template match expressions:

```
<xsl:template match="image[meta/@width &gt; meta/@height]">
  <!-- logic for wide image -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image">
  <!-- logic for not-wide image -->
</xsl:template>
```

And now you can just apply templates to all the images in one go without the `choose`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$image-entry/image"/>
```

To ignore the caption if there's no source, I'd move the caption logic into another template matching the `source` element

```
<xsl:template match="source" mode="caption">
  <p class="full-width-caption">
      Image courtesy of: <a href="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="../title"/></a>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Then in the main template do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../source" mode="caption"/>
```

If there is a source this will produce a caption, if there isn't then it'll produce nothing.

Given the example you've just added to the question it looks like you want to exclude the caption no when the `source` element "doesn't exist" but rather if it *has no value*.  You can do this by changing the above `apply-templates` to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../source[string()]" mode="caption" />
```

This would add a caption for `<source handle="">something</source>` but not for `<source handle="" />`.

What this is doing is filtering so we only select the `../source` element if the `[string()]` predicate is true.  The `string()` function returns the "string value" of the context element (the `source` in this case) and a string in boolean context is treated as false if it is empty and true otherwise.  So in this case the effect is to apply templates to the `source` element only if it has a non-empty value.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! That works perfectly... Didn't realise you could use conditionals when apply templates! xpath is so different but so interesting. Unfortunatley the Caption thing didn't work. If I put it in each template it shows every time as before. If I put it in the main named one, it doesn't show on any? Still, the image thing is great. I would never have figured that out!

Comment: @AcidX, please post a relevant example portion of your source XML. In Symphony CMS, this can be seen by appending `?debug` to the end of the fronted page URL when logged in as a Symphony developer.

Comment: @DavidOliver Hey, I've updated the main post to show the debug for the image. That example has no source provided.

Comment: @AcidX I've added a suggestion based on this example.

Comment: Works great. I don't understand how that works at all. I will have to read up on string. Thanks a load! My template is much shorter and tidier now as well.